# How can I make a new instance of Class<?extends U> without constructing U in Java?

Tags: java, class, instance

I'm making a game similar to Spore's cell stage, in which you build organisms to fight other evolving organisms, in the game each `Organism` is made up of an `ArrayList` of `Cell`s.

There are diffrent types of Cells with diffrent behaviours, all of which have their own class which extends the Class `Cell`

When two organisms produce an offspring, I iterate through both their parents' ArrayLists and compare them cell-by-cell,
I can determine which type of Cell will be in that index(based off it's parents' cell in the same spot relative to the `CellNucleus`), and I want to create that exact type of Cell without having to list every type of Cell with if statements

*I acctually do the above more efficiently, but I've simplified it for readability*

Put simply, I'm making this function in a tools class, and I don't know how to complete it:

```
    public static Class<?extends Cell>copyCell(Class<?extends Cell> cellz)
    {

        return ?

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you have your `Cell` class implement a `CellCloning` interface? You can then simply call `cell.cloneCell()` which would return a new `Cell` of the same type with cloned fields.

Comment: Though the function is called 'cloneCell' it's not refering to a java class clone where all the fields are copyed, I should probably rename it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a factory method somewhere to do this, either as a separate factory object or as part of the Cell.

Alternatively the Java `clone()` and `Cloneable` method and interface will allow you to duplicate an object.

If you don't need the data of the cell copied and just need the class then (assuming there is a no argument constructor) you can use `cell.getClass().newInstance()`.

Comment: Wouldn't that just make a new Cell class? instead of the acctual type of Cell which extends Cell?

Comment: cell.getClass() will return the actual runtime type of the class, it doesn't matter what variable type the reference to it is stored inside.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Class#newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) and a generic method

```
public static <T extends Cell> T cloneCell(Class<T> cellz) {
    return cellz.newInstance();
}
```

Not sure, but I think the `T` class must have a constructor without parameters ;)
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
public static <T extends Cell> T cloneCell(T original) {
    T clone = original.getClass().newInstance();
    // Manually set the attributes of the clone
    return clone;
}
```

While this fixes your current approach, it doesn't work very well if different cell types have different attributes. For this I would take another approach like the one suggested by Tim B or Sotirios Delimanolis.